# How to print an entity bundle field from one with multiple values

Tags: entities

Struggling to find the answer to this. I have an entity called "school objects" which has a bundle called "homepage". One of the fields attached to this is called "Hero banners" and it allows multiple text values.

[image: Example]

All I want to do is print each value. I don't need to check for conditions, I don't need NIDs, I just want each value. I am not really a php developer but understand the basics of what it is doing. I was looking into the `EntityFieldQuery` code, but cannot get anything to print on a tpl file I am using.

The output I need, based on image attached, is simply:

```
<div class="value_1">images/symbol.png</div>
<div class="value_2">Let's make a difference</div>
<div class="value_3">Start today</div>
```

All I can find after a lot of searching is complex bits of code checking for conditions and stuff that I do not need. I need some kind of array I think so that my template looks like:

```
<div class="value_1">Value[0]</div>
<div class="value_2">Value[1]</div>
<div class="value_3">Value[2]</div>
```

All I got so far is this:

```
query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'school_objects')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'homepage')
  ->range(0, 14);
$result = $query->execute();
```

I have read the link to this on the Drupal site but cannot understand it or how to print what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and load the actual entity to get its field values.

The code assumes you have drupals entityTypeManager injected via dependency injection. Otherwise use `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()` isntead of `$this->entityTypeManager()`

```
// Get the entity ids.
$entityIds = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('school_objects')->getQuery()
  ->condition('type', 'homepage')
  // Add more conditions if you need.
  ->execute();
// I assume only one id is returned and reset the array. Otherwise go over 
// each Id with a foreach() and do this in a loop.
$entityId = reset($entityIds);
$schoolObject = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('school_objects')->load($entityId);
// Now get the values of your field. I assume the fields machine_name is 'field_hero_banners'. Adjust if needed.
$values = $schoolObject->get('field_hero_banners')->getValue()
// Loop over all values.
foreach ($values as $item) {
  $value = $item['value'];
}
```

Comment: This just breaks the page. Also this bit "\Drupal::entityTypeManager()" I tried instead of the other line and that also breaks the page. Do I add most of this code to the top of the page, then the loop bit between my html tags? I am total novice with php.

Comment: well, this code should be part of a Controller class or something similar. In a drupal way I'd add this code to a controller, prepare the array of values for a twig template, add a custom twig template with a loop to print those values between your html tags. You can't just put this code in a html file. That means this is part of a custom module. I could help you with that, but I doubt this would help you, given your little knowledge of php/drupal?

Comment: No idea what a controller class or a twig is. Was trying to adapt some existing php that is on a tpl file. But seems I am years away from that at the moment. Thanks for your help, this might help someone on a higher level than me.

Comment: I think the sample of code in the question for drupal 7, and your code snippet for drupal 8, @Rich Stevens which version of drupal you use ?

Comment: Drupal 7.I also made it this far now: `<?php $query=new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'school_objects')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'homepage');
$result=$query->execute();
if (!empty($result['school_objects'])) {
$nids=array_keys($result['school_objects']);
$entity_testimonails=entity_load('school_objects', $nids);
foreach($entity_testimonails as $testimonails) {
$wrapper=entity_metadata_wrapper('school_objects', $testimonails->id, array('bundle' => 'homepage'));}}?>
<!--html here-->
<h1><?php echo ($wrapper->field_hero_banners->value());?></h1>` .

Comment: ok where did you put that come, which hook , which file ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('school_objects', '353', array('bundle' => 'homepage'));
$homepage_hero_banners = $wrapper->field_hero_banners->value();
?>
<p><?php echo $homepage_hero_banners[1]; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $homepage_hero_banners[2]; ?></p>
```

It has taken 4 days for me to get this code. I truly hope this helps someone else!